# Passing params to mapped observable

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm fairly new to Observables, Promises, Angular 2, and Javascript.

My question is how do I get a reference to the "item" object here:

```
  getItemTransactions (item: Item): Observable<any> {
    // Do some stuff ...

    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In the mapped extractData helper?

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let json = res.json().body

    /// How do I assign back to item object here?
    item.some_property = json["some_property"]
  }
```

Code come from here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Map should be used to convert a type to another type. When using the http service you should convert your expected json result to some expected and known type. This can be done using `.json()` method on the response.
2. Use `subscribe` to then do something with the expected result from `.json()`.

All of your actions can be done in the expression body, you do not need separate methods for them. This is a mater of preference so whatever you choose is fine.

See code below.

```
getItemTransactions (item: Item): Observable<any> {
// Do some stuff ...

  return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                .map((res) => res.json()) // get the data from the json result. This is equivalent to writing {return res.json()}
                .subscribe((data) => {
                  this.doSomethingWithData(data, item); // pass that deserialized json result to something or do something with it in your expression
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
}

private doSomethingWithData(data: any, item: Item) {
  // Do some stuff ...

  item.some_property = data["some_property"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to re-assign a method parameter in the first place? You probably want to assign a class property instead (`this.item` vs `item`).

But if for some reason you really want to reassign the `item` param, you could always inline the `extractData` helper, i.e.:

```ts
getItemTransactions(item: Item): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                .map((res: Response) => {
                  item = res.json();  // Re-assign some value to `item`
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

It's probably NOT what you want to do. The usual pattern is to have a function return an observable and `subscribe()` to that observable somewhere else in your code. You can do the assignment **inside the subscribe callback**.

This would translate to the following code:

```ts
getItemTransactions(item: Item): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
}

// Somewhere else in your code
this.getItemTransactions(item: Item).subscribe(data => {
  item = data; // for instance
}
```